# how download Angular4

Tags: angular

I want to develop my first app with Angular4 technology into PHP Symfony project. I don't want to use NodeJS server for executing JS source code. But the official tutorial of angular4 didn't specify another way for installing angular4.

I didn't find CDN for Angular4.

How can find source code of Angular v4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think best option for you is to use `SystemJs` loading system. You need to download all builded angular code into a folder and give path to those files in your systemjs configuration. in this way you dont have to use any of the build system line webpack, cli, grunt or any npm.

Below is a typical systemjs configuration file.

```
**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api',
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

you can use this yo generator to quick start [yo: angular2 with systemjs](https://github.com/aniruddhadas9/generator-angular2-with-systemjs). as angular is in version 4 you need to find the umd build which will be inside the build folder.

There are other ways you can explore but I think you will face challenges as its a different path and most of the people are fllowing cli or webpack build system

Answer (score 3):

For running Angular 4 in your Machine(I hope it's linux). Install the angular cli [here](https://cli.angular.io/)

With Angular cli you can start your application very fast. Just follow the guidlines. Its easy and efficient. Make sure you also have node installed.

A little note about Angular Cli . Its used for creating your project environment will all the necessary resources you need to run your project.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as CDN For Angular4.

Angular is on ES6.
So the essential process is 
You write your ES6 Code & Transpile it to ES5.

Angular needs this dependencies which can be kept on CDN.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/core-js@2.4.1/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/reflect-metadata@0.1.3/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/systemjs@0.19.31/dist/system.js"></script>
```

Next you use SystemJS

a typical SystemJS file is

```
var angularVersion;
if(window.AngularVersionForThisPlunker === 'latest'){
  angularVersion = ''; //picks up latest
}
else {
  angularVersion = '@' + window.AngularVersionForThisPlunker;
}

System.config({
  //use typescript for compilation
  transpiler: 'typescript',
  //typescript compiler options
  typescriptOptions: {
    emitDecoratorMetadata: true
  },
  paths: {
    'npm:': 'https://unpkg.com/'
  },
  //map tells the System loader where to look for things
  map: {

    'app': './src',
    '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core'+ angularVersion + '/bundles/core.umd.js',
    '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common' + angularVersion + '/bundles/common.umd.js',
    '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler' + angularVersion  + '/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser' + angularVersion + '/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic' + angularVersion + '/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
    '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http' + angularVersion + '/bundles/http.umd.js',
    '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router' + angularVersion +'/bundles/router.umd.js',
    '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms' + angularVersion + '/bundles/forms.umd.js',
    '@angular/animations': 'npm:@angular/animations' + angularVersion + '/bundles/animations.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser/animations': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser' + angularVersion + '/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js',
    '@angular/animations/browser': 'npm:@angular/animations' + angularVersion + '/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js',

    '@angular/core/testing': 'npm:@angular/core' + angularVersion + '/bundles/core-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/common/testing': 'npm:@angular/common' + angularVersion + '/bundles/common-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/compiler/testing': 'npm:@angular/compiler' + angularVersion + '/bundles/compiler-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser' + angularVersion + '/bundles/platform-browser-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic' + angularVersion + '/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/http/testing': 'npm:@angular/http' + angularVersion + '/bundles/http-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/router/testing': 'npm:@angular/router' + angularVersion + '/bundles/router-testing.umd.js',
    'tslib': 'npm:tslib@1.6.1',
    'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
    'typescript': 'npm:typescript@2.2.1/lib/typescript.js'
  },
  //packages defines our app package
  packages: {
    app: {
      main: './main.ts',
      defaultExtension: 'ts'
    },
    rxjs: {
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
  }
});
```

See this line

```
'npm:': 'https://unpkg.com/'
```

This is where you can provide your CDN.

Demo example 
https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=preview

Then in your index.html
you tell to load the app.

```
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script>
    System.import('app')
      .catch(console.error.bind(console));
  </script>
```